# Show that this map isn't a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

I need some help with this exercise.

Let $g:]-\pi/2,\pi/2[ \to R^2, \Theta \to \sin(\Theta)\cos(\Theta)(\cos(\Theta),\sin(\Theta))$.

Now let $M$ be the image of $g$.

I'm asked to decide, wether M is a submanifold or not.

There is a hint which told me to look how many components a small enough neighbourhood of $(0,0)$ in $M$ without $(0,0)$ has.

The answer should be two, as i can write the neigbourhood as a union of the $(x,y)$ which are right of $(0,0)$ and the values $(-x,y)$ which are at the opposite site.

Can anyone tell me how to proceed?

Comment: In an even smaller neighborhood of $(0,0)$, you should get $4$ components.

Comment: Why? Could you explain this to me?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  In a certain neighborhood of $(0,0)$, it is true that you get $2$ connected components (shown below)
[image]

But if you choose a smaller neighborhood of $(0,0)$, you get $4$ connected components (shown below)
[image]
Now why does this show that $M$ isn't a submanifold?  If it were, $(0,0)$ would have a neighborhood $U$ homeomorphic (via a map $\varphi$) to an open subset $V$ of $\mathbb R$.  Restricting if necessary, we may assume $V$ is an open interval.  Removing $(0,0)$ from $U$ leaves $4$ connected components, while removing $\varphi(0,0)$ leaves $2$ connected components.  But $U\setminus\{(0,0)\}$ is homeomorphic to $V\setminus\{\varphi(0,0)\}$, a contradiction.

Comment: I don't see where are 4 connected components.. there is just the one conmected component on the left side of $M$ and thr one connected component on the right side.. I furthermore don't see what this has to do with the fact that $M$ isn't a submanifold...

Comment: The second picture is of a neighborhood of $(0,0)$ in $M$, smaller than the whole space (we ignore everything not shown).  Removing $(0,0)$ leaves $4$ curves, the $4$ components.

Comment: I got you! But how can I use this fact to show that $M$ isn't a manifold?

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: I edited my answer to explain why this means $M$ isn't a submanifold.  Let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: I'll look at it tomorrow as I go to sleep now. I'll let you know if i understood everthing :) thank you!

Comment: You're welcome.  Glad to help!

Comment: I think i got it. g is just a parametrisation and everthing else follows from looking at the connected components and the fact that g is a homeomorphism. Thanks (once again :P)

Comment: One last thing i wonder about is how V has two components. Aren't it three? As i need three open intervals to parametrize the lower pic.

Comment: $V$ is some $(a,b)$, and $c=\varphi(0,0)\in(a,b)$.  Then $(a,b)\setminus\{c\}=(a,c)\cup(c,b)$ has two connected components.

Comment: But why can i say that V is an open iterval? To parametrize the curve on the pic below I need three intervals. One of the form $(-pi/2,a)$ one of the form $(-b,b)$ and one of the form $(c,pi/2)$. Sorry for my many questions but I want to understand evertyhing in a proper way. I see g as a local parametrisation. Is that false?

Comment: No, don't view $g$ as a parametrization.  Once you have $M$, forget about $g$.  Then look at the second picture.  This is a neighborhood $U$ of $(0,0)$ which, if $M$ were a manifold, would be homeomorphic to an open subset $V$ of $\mathbb R$.  since $U$ is connected, so is $V$, so $V$ is an interval.  Then look at my previous comment.

Comment: How can I say that $V$ has to be a subset of $R$. Why cant $V$ live in $R^2$?

Comment: Same problem, but removing a point from a ball in $\mathbb R^2$ leaves $1$ component.

Comment: Right. So I can say by the definition of the topological manifold (I guess it makes no difference that I'm looking at a differentiable manifold as this just has some extre structures) there has to be a homeomorphism to some $R^n$ and than I use the argument with the connnected components and I'm done.

Comment: Yep that's correct

Comment: Ok, cool! Every beginning is hard.